# Inkscape How to create outer border after Clip 'Set'?

Tags: inkscape, stroke, borders

Not sure I am asking this correctly. Here's my problem,

Originally, I perform 'Object' --> 'Clip' --> 'Set' on 2 images.

Here's the result:

[image]

Note that the pink color object is successfully contained inside the black object. But this is the case when the black object has no stroke/border.

Now, what i want to do, is to apply a border on the black object. If i do so, this happens:

[image]

Now, as observed, after applying a border/stroke, the pink object inside becomes mis-aligned. Why it isn't contained inside the black object anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red part does not change its position. The problem here is that svg strokes are centered on the object outline. If you have a stroke of width 8px, 4px of that stroke will overlap the object and the other 4px of the stroke will increase the object size. The following animation shows how the stroke is placed.

[image: svg stroke placement]

To get an outline that does not overlap your black object

- Duplicate the black object (select and `ctrl+d`).
- Set a stroke on the duplicate. The stroke should be twice as wide as intended.
- Put the stroke into the background (select and `end`).

Alternatively, disable the fill of the duplicate and move it to the front (select and `Pos 1`).

Comment: As of Inkscape v0.91, if you add `paint-order:stroke fill;` to the object's `style` property, then it will render the fill in front of the stroke.  I think v0.92 also adds a GUI option.